# SQLite always replies with "database table is locked"

Tags: c++, c, sqlite

If I execute these statements in my C++ program (`%s` stands for a select statement, which can vary, please assume there is no error in `%s`).

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp AS %s;
DROP TABLE tmp;
COMMIT;
```

Then sqlite3 always replies with `database table is locked`, except when I don't drop the table at the end. The statements are executed with `sqlite3_exec()`. There are other questions like this online, but without answers, for example:

http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/How-is-the-table-getting-locked-and-how-to-unlock-it-td58324.html

I suspect the `PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;PRAGMA synchronous=OFF;` is to blame, but I am not certain. Also, perhaps executing and finalizing the statements one by one might also work? Can I check if a table is currently locked?

Comment: Why are you using shared-cache mode?

Comment: @CL Not that I knew... How to disable?

Comment: You're using `sqlite3_enable_shared_cache()` or `SQLITE_OPEN_SHAREDCACHE`.

Comment: @CL. You're right, amazing. How did you know?

Comment: Because table locks exist only in shared-cache mode. Please write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `sqlite3_enable_shared_cache()` or `SQLITE_OPEN_SHAREDCACHE`.
                    – CL.